# what activation function use in the last layer

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

iam developing a network to detemine if the object is a character or not to input it on the classification network but iam curios about the last layer to my output, should I use sigmoid and consider object less than 70 percent not character or use softmax and classifies it as character and not character

Comment: Honestly, you should test both to see which one gives better predictions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a binary classifier use sigmoid or if there are more than two classes use softmax instead. This is the general rule but feel free to change the activations because things like these are affected manly by the type of data